# hacer JSON a partir de consulta PHP

Tags: php

Quiero hacer una consulta a una tabla para obtener los datos en JSON para poder después mostrarlos en el cliente. Hago una búsqueda concreta y obtengo la salida, pero según los datos que obtengo no estoy segura de que lo esté haciendo bien.

```
$elemento=!empty($_GET['elemento']) ? $_GET['elemento'] : NULL;

$statement = $cnn->prepare("SELECT
        id, name, id_grupo, grupo, description, autor, principal, imagen
    FROM table
    WHERE id = $elemento ORDER BY id");

$valor = $statement->execute();
    
if( $valor ){
    while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $datos["data"][] = $resultado;
    }
    echo json_encode( $datos );

}else{
    echo "No hay datos";
}
$statement->closeCursor();
$conexion = null;
```

el JSON que obtengo

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "name1",
      "id_grupo": 1,
      "grupo": "grupo1",
      "description": "Se distingue por sus colores vivos",
      "autor": "Pedro Sanchez",
      "principal": true,
      "imagen": "imagen01.jpg",
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "name1",
      "id_grupo": 1,
      "grupo": "grupo1",
      "description": "Se distingue por sus colores vivos",
      "autor": "Pedro Sanchez",
      "principal": false,
      "imagen": "imagen02.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "name1",
      "id_grupo": 1,
      "grupo": "grupo1",
      "description": "Se distingue por sus colores vivos",
      "autor": "Pedro Sanchez",
      "principal": false,
      "imagen": "imagen03.jpg"
    }
 ]
}
```

El 2º y el 3º elemento del JSON debería ser sólo uno que tuviera 2 imágenes, no?

*********** UPDATE *********
Usando el método de @A.Cedano

```
$sql="SELECT
        CONCAT_WS(
          '',
          '{'
          '\"id\":',table1.id,
          ',\"name\":\"',table1.name,'\"'
          ',\"id_grupo\":',table1.id_grupo,
          ',\"grupo\":\"',table1.grupo,'\"'
          ',\"description\":\"',table1.description,'\"'
          ',\"autor\":\"',images.autor,'\"'
          ',\"principal\":',
              '[',
                  GROUP_CONCAT(images.principal SEPARATOR ','),
              ']'
          ',\"imagen\":',
                  '[',
                      GROUP_CONCAT
                      (
                        CONCAT('\"',images.path_system::text || images.imagen::text AS imagen,'\"') SEPARATOR ','
                      ),
                  ']',
        '}'
        ) AS json
      FROM table1, images
        WHERE images.id = table1.id and table1.id = :id
        GROUP BY table1.id, table1.name, table1.id_grupo, table1.grupo, images.description, images.autor
        ORDER BY table1.id";  

$statement = $cnn->prepare($sql);
$params=array(":id"=>$elemento);
$valor = $statement->execute($params);
    
if( $valor ){
    while( $resultado = $statement->fetchColumn()){
        $datos["data"][] = json_decode($resultado);
    }
    var_dump($datos);

   }else{
        echo "error";
}
    
$statement->closeCursor();
$conexion = null;
```

así me da error. No se si el uso de varias tablas será el problema o como construyo la url que contiene la imagen, que es el path del servidor y el nombre de la imagen almacenados en la tabla de images. O no se si la solución pasaría por crear una vista con los datos de la consulta y atacar directamente a la vista en lugar de a las tablas, la url de la imagen ya estaría construido. No se ...

*** edición ***

**directamente no entra** en el bucle while. al hacer `var_dump($elemento);` da el id que estoy introduciendo `string(1) "4"`. Estoy usando Postgress como motor de base de datos.

Comment: Varias cosas. Usas sentencias `prepare` pero le pones la variable `$elemento` dentro de la consulta directamente. De este modo no se esta escapando el valor de `$elemento`. La forma correcta seria mediante el uso de `?` en la consulta y luego poner la variable $elemento en el `$valor = $statement->execute($elemento);` o bien usando funciones [bind*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php).  Y en cuanto al JSON, es correcto, pues tu consulta devuelve un array con tres resultados y al realizar el json_encode se muestran tal como ves

Comment: Me parece que lo que necesitas es hacer una consulta SQL que te agrupe los datos, usando `GROUP BY` quizá combinado con `GROUP_CONCAT`. Realmente, el elemento en sí es el mismo, y tú puedes tener una propiedad que sea un array para los valores repetidos, por ejemplo: **`"imagenes":["imagen01.jpg", "imagen02.jpg", "imagen03.jpg"]`** Es algo que debes trabajar en tu instrucción SQL, armando el JSON de la mejor forma y con la menor redundancia posible.

Comment: ¿Qué error da la consulta? Aún no queda claro si quieres una lista de imágenes o con una basta ¿? Si basta con una, como dije en otro comentario, no necesitas concatenar, sino poner `MAX`  y agrupar.

Comment: Pues está saliendo el mensaje de error que le puesto en el ```if( $valor ){``` así que no está haciendo nada. He puesto un echo de $valor @A.Cedano, incluso de $params sale un NOTICE: Notice: Array to string conversion in http://www.mipagina.php on line 73
Array. Respecto a las imágenes, para un ID pude haber varias imágenes, mientras que para otro ID puede haber solamente una... entonces si que habría que concatenar

Comment: @Claudia en el `else` agrega temporalmente un `var_dump($cnn->errorInfo());` y dinos qué muestra. Es muy probable que la consulta SQL haya quedado con algún error de sintaxis.

Comment: Esto es lo que sale @A.Cedano ```array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }```

Comment: Entonces el problema quizá es que `$elemento` es un array ¿? Pon un `var_dump($elemento);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Pongo el ```var_dump($lemento)```en el else y lo que da es el resultado del iID que le envío en el SELECT ```string(2) "16"```@A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Sigue saliendo esto: `Array to string conversion in mipagina.php on line ...` ? Si sigue saliendo di cuál es la línea de ese error. Otra cosa, ¿cuál es tu gestor de base de datos? Es que veo sintaxis de PostgreSQL en tu código.

Comment: por lo que puedo ver, directamente no entra en el ```while( $resultado = $statement->fetchColumn())```Y si, estoy usando PostgreSQL @A.Cedano

Answer (score 5):

El problema que veo en tu código es la **redundancia de datos**. Estás transportando **tres veces** un objeto con datos casi idénticos. Esto es como irte de viaje y pensar la compra de billetes en función de la cantidad de imágenes que tienes que llevar: tres imágenes, tres billetes ... ¡100 imágenes, 100 billetes!. No, debes comprar un billete por persona, y que cada uno lleve sus imágenes en la maleta: 1 persona, 1 billete. Pues eso: **la redundancia de datos es costosa, y puede llegar a ser una ruina para el sistema**.

Tú puedes construir un sólo objeto, donde agrupes en un array los posibles repetidos. Para ello te puedes hacer ayudar de `CONCAT_WS`, combinado con `GROUP_CONCAT` y con `GROUP BY` (en versiones modernas de MySQL dispones de funciones para crear consultas en forma de objetos JSON con mayor simplicidad).

Concatenando, tu consulta quedaría así (**ojo a los comentarios en algunas partes del código**):

```
$sql="SELECT
        CONCAT_WS(
          '',
          '{'
          '\"id\":',id,
          ',\"name\":\"',name,'\"'
          ',\"id_grupo\":',id_grupo,
          ',\"grupo\":\"',grupo,'\"'
          ',\"description\":\"',description,'\"'
          ',\"autor\":\"',autor,'\"'
          ',\"principal\":',
              '[',
                  GROUP_CONCAT(principal SEPARATOR ','),
              ']'
          ',\"imagen\":',
                  '[',
                      GROUP_CONCAT
                      (
                        CONCAT('\"',imagen,'\"') SEPARATOR ','
                      ),
                  ']',
        '}'
        ) AS json
      FROM table
        WHERE id = :id
        GROUP BY id, name, id_grupo, grupo, description, autor
        ORDER BY id";  

$statement = $cnn->prepare($sql);
$params=array(":id"=>$elemento);
$valor = $statement->execute($params);
    
if( $valor ){
    /*
      La consulta arrojará una sola columna llamada json
      con una cadena correctamente formateada
      al estilo JSON
      Haremos la conversión de inmediato
      y lo que tendremos en $datos
      será ya un array de objetos JSON.
      Y dado que la consulta ahora arroja
      una sola columna, usaremos fetchColumn()
    */
      
    while( $resultado = $statement->fetchColumn()){
        $datos["data"][] = json_decode($resultado);
    }
    /*
       Usamos var_dump para verificar el objeto
       Si todo está OK, ahora usa $datos
       para aquello que necesites
       recordando que dentro tiene ya los objetos
       y que ninguna conversión es necesarioa
    */
    var_dump($datos);

    // Resto del código
```

Esto deberá arrojarte un objeto así más o menos:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "id":16,
      "name":"name1",
      "id_grupo":1,
      "grupo":"grupo1",
      "description":"Se distingue por sus colores vivos",
      "autor":"Pedro Sanchez",
      "principal":[true,false,false],
      "imagen":[
        "imagen01.jpg",
        "imagen02.jpg",
        "imagen03.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Luego donde recibas este objeto puedes determinar, por su posición, el valor de los valores agrupados en `principal` y en `imagen`. Como dije en el comentario del código, ya tendrás en cada miembro del array un objeto, no tienes que hacer ninguna conversión, sino tratar a cada elemento de `$datos` como un objeto directamente.

#### PD

- He probado la consulta SQL y funciona correctamente (la consulta de la respuesta original necesitaba ser afinada un poco).
- He implementado además **consultas preparadas reales** poniendo un marcador donde irían los datos externos y pasando esos datos en el `execute`  asociados al marcador en un array.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que ahi en la Query que usas puede fallar por que si el id es null te jalara solo los que tengan el id nulo y como un id no puede estar nulo creo yo si es llave te mandara un error

Ahora, para lo que necesitas es un `json_encode` para mostrar y para mandar es `json_decode` asi los datos se mandan en json y puedes usarlos en donde tu quieras siempre y cuando no los muestres por que ahi si te arrojara error

Lo que no entiendo bien es tu pregunta, quieres que el resultado 2 y 3 te salga en una sola cadena o esta bien asi?

Comment: `json_docode` no existe. Y para "mandar" es **json_encode** pues crea un json usable por las peticiones ajax.  La función contraria seria `json_decode` y te transformaria un **json** en un _array_ u _objeto_ de PHP.  En este caso lo que tiene es un _array_ ($datos) que quiere devolver en formato **json**, por lo tanto eso lo hace bien.

Comment: correccion, json_decode

Comment: Vale, pero sigues diciendo lo otro al reves, o eso me parece a mi

Comment: El problema que yo veo aquí es **la redundancia**. Se están transportando **tres objetos casi idénticos** (como pagar 3 veces el billete aéreo) cuando los puedes convertir en uno solo para lograr esto: `{"data":[{"id":16,"name":"name1","id_grupo":1,"grupo":"grupo1","description":"Se distingue por sus colores vivos","autor":"Pedro Sanchez","principal":true,"imagenes":["imagen01.jpg","imagen02.jpg","imagen03.jpg"]}]}` Es decir: **las imágenes juntas**. Eso es sumamente fácil con `GROUP_CONCAT`  combinado con `GROUP BY` (en caso de que OP use MySQL), y si es otro SGBD, igualmente, agrupando.

Comment: Si, entiendo, pero lo que no entiendo es la frase del OP que dice `El 2º y el 3º elemento del JSON debería ser sólo uno que tuviera 2 imágenes, no?`, pues no se que pretende realmente... dos objetos siendo uno con solo una imagen y el otro con el resto de imagenes?  Creo que no lo tiene claro

Comment: @masterguru quizá sea por la diferencia en la propiedad llamada `principal`, es `false` en el 2º y 3º. Si hay diferencias en ese elemento, puede hacer lo mismo: **agrupar en una sola propiedad:** `"principales":[true,false,false]`. Transportar objetos repetidos es muy costoso. Es como si quieres llevar tres fotos y pagas un billete aéreo por cada foto... ¿¡por qué no las llevas en la maleta (el único objeto que transporta las fotos)!?

Comment: Vale, ahora lo pillo, gracias, pues nada, que arregle la consulta y acondicione el código que va a interpretar esa agrupación y listos

Comment: Si, ya veo que el problema puede ser la consulta porque realmente debería mostrar un solo resultado agrupado y no 3. Hago el ```echo json_encode();``` para recogerlo en javascript.  Siempre va a haber un true en imagen, porque siempre va a haber por lo menos una imagen, puede haber más imágenes o no, pero siempre va a haber una que sea true, como también el ID siempre va a haber un ID. Entonces como dice @A.Cedano si deba agrupar.

Comment: @Claudia si no necesitas todos los resultados repetidos (de `imagen` y de `principal`) es aún más simple, basta con poner en el `SELECT` de tu consulta original una agrupación: `MAX(imagen) AS imagen, MAX(principal) AS principal`  y al final agregar **`GROUP BY id`**. Así te traerá una fila por cada `id` y en cuanto a esas dos columnas el mayor (si quieres el menor usas `MIN`).

Comment: @A.Cedano me da error. En realidad utilizo varias tablas para la consulta, no es tan simple como esa. Voy a editar la pregunta poniendo como udpate la consulta.